# Duplicants not collecting water

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have two buildings that require water in my base, a Supercomputer and an Algae Terrarium. I also have an access to water for my duplicates but for some reason they do not try to get water from it. Both the buildings have been sitting there for about 2 cycles without any duplicate watering them. I have even tried changing the priorities but without effect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiFJy.jpg
(The screens were too large so I had to upload them on Imgur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the recent patch (that introduced germs), they add a new structure that pump up water for your duplicants to use.

You have to make sure that this new structure has access to water below itself.

I believe they did this so that you can block duplicant access to certain water if they pose a problem for your base if you use them. Previously duplicant would just grab whatever water that they can reach no matter what the consequence.

[image]

Comment: The Dupes still collect every bottled water lying around in your base (from clean-up tasks or dropped during transport)